# Println in loop and closure output different values

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
dirs, err      := get_directories(bucket, start_dir, "")
```

Where dirs is an array of strings. After that, I'm looping over them:

```
for _, dir     := range dirs {
  fmt.Println("le dir",dir)
  go func() {
    fmt.Println("working on",dir)
    get_files(bucket, dir, "")
    wg.Done()
  }()
}

wg.Wait()
```

In dirs, I have ["one", "two"], and if I see the following content:

```
le dir one
le dir two
working on one
working on one
```

Why is the gorouting not using the correct value of `dir`?

Comment: I first thought this was undefined behavior, but each iteration of the loop creates a new dir that is independent of the previous one.

Comment: It seems this holds the answer: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CommonMistakes

Comment: @Tempus That discusses the *opposite* behavior than the behavior reported (which confuses me) - in the reported behavior the *first* value is printed twice in the closure.

Comment: @Tempus - I got bit by that one [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19192377/823393) - good call.

Comment: @user2864740 "there is a very good chance that when you run this code you will see the last element printed for every iteration" -- keyword being *chance*. The scheduler may not make the choice you expect, so it's possible it will print the *first* value twice, or even that it will print the first and then the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating multiple threads of execution (goroutines), which aren't guaranteed to execute in any particular order (this is the nature of concurrency). Because of this, it's theoretically possible for the main thread to finish its loop before the scheduler dispatches any of the goroutines. This is probably what you're experiencing.

Because the main loop has finished executing before any of the goroutines executes its first instruction, `dir` has arrived at its final value, and so each goroutine will use that (*not* the value of `dir` when the closure was created).

If you looped more times (more elements in `dirs`) or if each loop iteration took a lot longer to execute (for example, if you `Wait()`ed in your loop), you would probably start to see some intermingling between the print statements of your main routine and those of your goroutines.

Here is a simplified, idiomatic rewrite of your example, for others who might find this question useful:

http://play.golang.org/p/6G_8xOi9Fi

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan bool)

    // with 1000 iterations, you can probably see some intermingling
    // between lines printed via goroutines and those of your main thread
    for i:=0;i<1000;i++ {
        fmt.Println("before kicking off goroutine:", i)
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("in goroutine:", i)
            ch1 <- true // signal 'done'
        }()
        // alternatively, add a `time.Wait()` here
        // (and reduce the loop iterations) to see
        // intermingling for a different reason.
    }

    <- ch1 // wait for goroutines to complete
}
```

Comment: Isn't it that each iteration of the for loop creates its own dir variable that is independent of the others? Am I missing something?

Comment: @FUZxxl Nope, consider this: http://play.golang.org/p/JK49dDBCQ_. When the goroutine modifies the counter, it becomes modified for the main thread as well, and the loop quits. If each thread had its own copy, modifying the value in a goroutine would have no affect on the value in the main thread.

Comment: In your snippet, won't it stop after receiving just one value from the channel ?